# jadira usertype timezone

Tags: spring, hibernate, jodatime

I'm using jadira usertype + joda time in my project. I'm using hibernate + spring.
My bean pojo use spring annotations as @CreatedDate and org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener that automatically set the creation date on the bean when it is saved.
I am in Europe/Rome Timezone but unfortunally in the db the date is stored as UTC, instead when I display the value on the client (javafx) the date is show in the correctly timezone.

How can I store data in db in the correct timezone?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the property "jadira.usertype.databaseZone".

Either set it to an explicit timezone, or "jvm" to use whatever the default timezone of the JVM is.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
p:jpaProperties-ref="jpaProps" />

<util:properties id="jpaProps">
  <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
  <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
  <prop key="jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes">true</prop>
  <!-- defaults to storing UTC dates in DB otherwise -->
  <prop key="jadira.usertype.databaseZone">jvm</prop>
  <prop key="jadira.usertype.javaZone">jvm</prop>
</util:properties>
```

Comment: For clarity - the above properties can be added wherever you're currently setting the hibernate properties for example "hibernate.dialect"